# How to Chain Asynchronous Calls and Propagate Exceptions with CompletableFuture in Spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous, completable-future

I'm very new to multi-threading and `CompletableFuture`, and I wanted to know if it is possible to implement the following scenario in Spring container (Spring Boot 2) and `@Async`.

I have several services that basically construct a larger object, and I wanted to see if I can make the granular services run asynchronously.

I have a service (`ServiceC`) that depends on the output of another service (`ServiceA`), while the third one can run independently (`ServiceB`). `someService` is needed for all the other services, so I thought I don't need to make it an asynchronous call. Below is the layout:

```
@Service
public class ServiceA {
  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<A> doServiceAWork(int id) throws AppException {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(getA(id));
  }
}


@Service
public class ServiceB {
  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<B> doServiceBWork(int id) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(getB(id));
  }
}


@Service
public class ServiceC {
  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<C> doServiceCWork(A a) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(getC(a));
  }
}

@Service
public class ServiceOrchestration {
  // Necessary autorwiring of services

  public BigObj constructBigObj(AppObj obj) throw SomeAppException {
    int id = someService.getId(obj);
    BigObj bigObj = new BigObj();

    try {
      // Conceptualizing here
      CompletableFuture<A> cfA = serviceA.doServiceAWork(id);
      CompletableFuture<B> cfB = serviceB.doServiceBWork(id);

      // Obviously C depends on A
      CompletableFuture<C> cfC = serviceB.doServiceCWork(cfA.get());

      CompletableFuture.allOf(cfA, cfB, cfC).join();

      bigObj.setA(cfA.get());
      bigObj.setB(cfB.get());
      bigObj.setC(cfC.get());

    } catch (AppException | ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
      throw new SomeAppException("..", e);
    }

    return BigObj;
  }
}
```

My requirements are as following:

- Invoke asynchronous call to `ServiceC` when `ServiceA` is done as the returned data should be fed to `ServiceC` in order to proceed
- If a call to `ServiceA` throws an exception (`AppException`), it needs to be propagated to the caller -- in this case `ServiceOrchestration#constructBigObject()`, which handles it as above. In other word, if `serviceA.doServiceAWork(id)` throws an exception, every other asynchronous call should be canceled but the exception should be thrown in `constructBigObj` in order to be caught and handled
- Wait for all the asynchronous calls to be completed then construct `BigObj`

For the second requirement, I looked at `isCompletedExceptionally()` but wasn't sure where it needs to be called from, e.g. before a call to `join()`? How do I get the root exception then?

How does the asynchronous chaining works here between `ServiceA` call and `ServiceC` where there are dependencies for calling one, at the same time, I need values from both, e.g. `A` and `C`, to construct `BigObj`?